# Query Help - String in where clause has & character

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I am running an SQL (Oracle) statement like that

```
select * from table 
where table_id in ('265&310', '266&320')
```

While running through TOAD, it consider ***&*** as some variable placeholder and it asks for its value. If it was for 1-2 place holders then I could have set it in TOAD but the in clause has like 200 of strings.

How to put this query?

I want to export the DATASET as SQL INSERT statement, so I can't use this in SQL-PLUS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TOAD, you can disable the prompt for substitution variables from the options dialog:

You need to uncheck:
View –> Toad Options –> Execute/Compile –> Prompt for Substitution variables.

Answer (score 7):

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
```

Will work to turn the prompting for variable off..

or

```
SET ESCAPE ON;
SELECT 'blah \& blah' AS DES FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: is there any optino to set define off or set define ~ in TOAD?

Comment: That works when running as a script, but TOAD uses it's own parser for running individual statments. Fortunately, you can disable substitution from the Options menu, as I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can escape the ampersand character by using concatenation, like this:

```
select * from table 
where table_id in ('265' || '&' || '310', '266' || '&' || '320')
```

Comment: this is gona be lots of effort :(

Comment: Another option is to do as Randy suggested and, for example, to set the DEFINE character to something else or off altogether. SET DEFINE ~;