# Subversion Oracle variable replacement

Tags: oracle, svn

When undoing a checkout of a package body using Toad & Subversion with a package
that contains ampersands and set define turned off the text after the ampersand
is being changed to upper case.

For example:

```
cCCS_REQUEST := cCCS_REQUEST
||'&credit_exp=30&country=Canada&term='||TO_CHAR(nContract_Term);
```

is changed to :

```
cCCS_REQUEST := cCCS_REQUEST
||'&CREDIT_EXP=30&COUNTRY=Canada&TERM='||TO_CHAR(nContract_Term);
```

Anyone know how to get around this?

Thanx

Comment: undoing a svn checkout? I thought checkout was to get a working copy of a repository. How do you undo this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020709/query-help-string-in-where-clause-has-character

Answer (score 0):

There must be some way in Toad and SQL Developer SVN clients to not do such a substitution. However, you might be able to use the `CHR()` function to encode your ampersands:

```
cCCS_REQUEST := cCCS_REQUEST
||CHR(38)||'credit_exp=30'||CHR(38)||'country=Canada'||CHR(38)||'term='||TO_CHAR(nContract_Term);
```