# How to escape ampersand in TOAD?

Tags: sql, plsql, toad

When I try to insert a value which has '&' in TOAD I get a prompt for a substitution variable.

So when I try:

```
insert into x values('hello & world');
```

it throws a prompt for substituting the variable 'world'.

I have tried right clicking in the editor and  disabling prompt for substitution variables but this seems to work only for Execute Statement (<kbd>F9</kbd>)  It doesn't work for Execute as script(<kbd>F5</kbd>).

I am also aware of using `chr(38)` like:

```
insert into x values('hello '||chr(38)||'world');
```

but I do not want this.
Is there something else that will help me run the script?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020709/query-help-string-in-where-clause-has-character

Comment: I am looking for a different solution. The accepted answer says about disabling prompt for substitution variables. But as mentioned in my question I have tried this.

Comment: The link I provided has also other answers, not only the accepted solution.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try putting `set define off` at the beginning of your script. It should work with <kbd>F5</kbd>:

```sql
set define off;
insert into x values('hello & world'); 
set define on;
```

Answer (score 12):

In TOAD version 12.120.39
Right click in Editor and Click in Substitution Variable Prompting and select none

This worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

set define off doesn't work in TOAD just in sqlplus.

You can disable substitution variable support by right-clicking in the Editor and
unchecking the “Prompt for Substitution Variables” item. It works with F9 execution but not with F5 (script) execution.
With F5 you need to add "set define off" in the first line then launch with F5!!
(hope this help it was very hard to find for me)

Comment: I just used `SET DEFINE OFF` to resolve this issue while using Toad 12.8.0.49

Answer (score 0):

I use toad 16.1 and disabling on editor "Substitution Variable Prompting = none"  works all the time