# How to use variables in a select statement in Oracle PL-SQL

Tags: oracle

I have a simple query that I can run in toad.

```
select * from my_table 
where my_id = 11111;
```

Why can't I run the same query from toad this time declaring a variable and using it in the where clause?

In sql server I would:

```
declare @testID int
set @testID = 11111
select * from my_table 
    where my_id = @testID;
```

How can I accomplish the same in Oracle 11g?

Comment: depends.. .if you're doing this for testing and you want to capture the value at runtime you could just `select * from my_table 
    where my_id = &testID;`  ampersand denotes variable requiring user input when executed.   Be cautious of this in Oracle as if you have a name like Mike & Jon's Paint and body    it may ask you to define Jon variable! (this can be disabled: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735499/how-to-escape-ampersand-in-toad))

Comment: For similar question, Answer already given earlier.
Check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163996/how-to-select-into-a-variable-in-pl-sql-when-the-result-might-be-null)

Comment: @xQbert I have multiple "select * from tables where id = &id" queries. If i will add &id , it will prompt me everytime query is getting executed. Can I do something to make prompt once, & the use the same value again & again.

Comment: @ASharma7  Untested but this concept should work: use a selct statement and cross join to the the variable  `SELECT A.*, Z.MyTestValue FROM tableName A cross join (Select &myTestValue myTestValue from dual) Z ` but that only works  if you can union the results  of you multiple selects and do the cross join after the union.  This is a different question: I recommend asking a new one. if the above doens't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PLSQL is different than SQL SERVER. It has its own syntax. See how you can do it as below:

```
DECLARE
   var    NUMBER := 1;
   var2   my_table%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT *
     INTO var2
     FROM my_table
    WHERE my_id = var;

  --To display result you need to add dbsm_output.put_line function.

  dbms_output.put_line(var2.<columnname>);

Exception
When others then
 Null;       
END;
```

Note: Assumption is that the query wil return a single row only.

Comment: To see out you first need to display it using dbms_output.put_line function.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the results. (My output is enabled in toad)
declare 
    p_jobID number(6) := 111111;
    p_row JOBS%rowtype;

begin

select * 
into p_row
from my_table 
where id = p_jobID;

Dbms_Output.put_line(:p_row);
end;

Comment: You need to mention p_row.columnname like p_row.x where x is a column of your table my_table

Comment: So if my table has 30 columns then I have to specify all 30 columns?

Comment: Yes,,thats true..!! Like Dbms_Output.put_line(p_row.col1 ||  p_row.col2 ..and so on) where || is pipe to join the result set

Comment: Thank you.  Seems like I have to jump through hoops more in Oracle then sql server.

Comment: Not more hoops, just different ones. What is it you're going to do with the results of that sql query? Are you passing the information back to a calling procedure outside of the db?

Answer (score 6):

In Toad (or SQL Developer) you can do this:

```
select * from my_table 
where my_id = :testID;
```

When you run it, you will be prompted to enter a value for the testId bind variable.

Comment: I have multiple "select * from tables where id = &id" queries. If i will add &id , it will prompt me everytime query is getting executed. Can I do something to make prompt once, & the use the same value again & again.

Comment: @ASharma7 Yes, you can use `@@id`